# Object not found error in anova

Tags: r, csv, session, anova

I am new to coding and R and am trying to run an anova on my dataset for a project. I am looking for the effect of condition on response times (resp.rt). I keep getting the following error though:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'resp.rt' not found
```

Here is my code:

```
setwd('C:/Users/Dasha/Documents/R/stroop')

files <- list.files(path = ".", pattern = "_stroop.csv")

data_frame <- do.call(rbind,lapply(files,read.csv, header = T))


  print(i)


#Change independent variables to factors
data_frame$congruent <- as.factor(data_frame$congruent)
data_frame$session <- as.factor(data_frame$session)
data_frame$participant <- as.factor(data_frame$participant)

model_rt <- lm (resp.rt ~ participant + session + congruent + condition + condition*session, data_frame = data_frame)

anova(model_rt)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your data_frame variable (descriptive) most likely does not have a "resp.rt" field...

Comment: I used str(data_frame) to check if the column is there and got this output (it seems like it is there indeed):
'data.frame': 20879 obs. of  6 variables:
    $ congruent  : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 1 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
    $ resp.corr  : int  1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
    $ resp.rt    : num  0.732 0.734 0.517 0.685 0.567 ...
    $ session    : Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
    $ participant: Factor w/ 58 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
    $ condition  : Factor w/ 3 levels "baseline","HR",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...